# flutter firebase authentication FirebaseUser problem

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

```
final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
registerNewUser(BuildContext context)async
{
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = (await _firebaseAuth
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: emailTextEditingController.text,
            password: passwordTextEditingController.text)).user;

}

final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
registerNewUser(BuildContext context)async
{
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = (await _firebaseAuth
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: emailTextEditingController.text,
            password: passwordTextEditingController.text)).user;

}
```

when I use FirebaseUser it show error

Comment: could you update your error logs?

Comment: Which error? Please, describe a little your process.

Answer (score 1):

You should use **User** Instead of **FirebaseUser**

```
 User firebaseUser = (await _firebaseAuth.......
```

Answer (score 0):

User catchError to see the issue you are getting in your logs

```
firebaseAuth
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: _emailTextCotroller.text,
          password: _passwordTextCotroller.text,
        )
        .then((user) => {
               // create user into database
            })
        .catchError((e) => {print(e.toString())});

    Navigator.pushReplacement(
        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()));
```